# Very basic python question

Tags: python, data, python-3.x, programming, code

I am doing the free interactive learn python tutorial, and I am on the first conditions lesson. The task was to make it so that every statement in the following code resolved true. The code below was my response and it was marked correct, but I don't understand why the second to last item (specifically, first_array == 1) is true. How is first_array equal to 1? I had to give first_array 3 numbers to make the other conditions true.

```
number = 16
second_number = 0
first_array = [1,2,3]
second_array = [1,2]

if number > 15:

    print("1")

if first_array:

    print("2")

if len(second_array) == 2:

    print("3")

if len(first_array) + len(second_array) == 5:

    print("4")

if first_array and first_array[0] == 1:

    print("5")

if not second_number:

    print("6")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're confused about

```py
if first_array and first_array[0] == 1:
    print("5")
```

Think about python parsing the code like this:

```py
if (condition_1 is True) and (condition_2 is True):
    print("5")
```

So what are `condition_1` and `condition_2`?

`condition_1` might seem weird if you're new to coding. `if first_array` evaluates `first_array` as a boolean. In python, empty arrays evaluate as `False` and nonempty arrays evaluate as `True`. You can test this by calling `bool` on various values.

```py
list1 = []
list2 = [1,2,3]

bool(list1)
>False

bool(list2)
>True
```

Note that this behavior is about evaluating the *list itself* and does not depend on what exactly is in the list

```py
list1 = [True]
list2 = [False]

bool(list1)
>True

bool(list2)
>True

# both lists evaluate as `True` because both lists are nonempty
```

Now for `condition_2`, `first_array[0] == 1`. This looks at the value of the first item in `first_array` and checks if it is equal to 1.

```py
first_array = [1,2,3]

first_array[0]==1
>True

first_array[1]==2
>True

first_array[1]==1
>False
```

To summarize, the statement `first_array and first_array[0] == 1` evaluates to `True` if `first_array` is nonempty and the first element of `first_array` is equal to `1`.